# One to one functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $f$ is a one-one function. Show that $f^{-1} \circ f(x) = x$
>   for all $x\in \mathbb{D}(f)$ and $f \circ f^{-1}(y) =y$ for all $y\in
>  \mathbb{R}(f)$.

What I understand from this is that since $x\in \mathbb{D}(f)$ and $f$ is one-one, then there exist elements $x_1$,$x_2$ where $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.

Comment: What you say you understand, doesn't make sense. It's very important in this kind of endeavor to get the definitions *exactly* right, not just sorta-kinda right, so I'd advise starting by understanding *exactly* what one-one means.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $f^{-1}\circ f$ in this case? Since $f$ is only one-to-one, we can't really speak of its inverse unless we know that it is also onto.

Comment: @ThomasE. I have no idea too. I am just learning this and it is a problem from the book.

Comment: Which book and what page? Maybe it means $f^{-1}( f\{x\})=\{x\}$ and $f(f^{-1}\{y\})=\{y\}$ for all such $x,y$.

Comment: @ThomasE. the book is "elements of real analysis" by bartle on page 22 problem 2F

Comment: @GerryMyerson is my wording now any better?

Comment: @ThomasE. $f^{-1}( f\{x\})=\{x\}$ is the same thing as $f^{-1} \circ f(x) = x$. The circle in between states for composition.

Comment: @Q.matin. In general, not. That's my whole point. Since in general you can only speak of pre-images of sets, i.e. $f^{-1}A$ for some $A\subset Y$, where $f^{-1}$ itself is not a function, but just a notation. So $f^{-1}\circ f$ is meaningless unless $f^{-1}$ exists as a function, which is equivalent for $f$ to be a bijection.

Comment: @ThomasE. I have a lot of studying to do then because I am not sure exactly what you said.

Comment: @Q.matin. In short, the function $f^{-1}$ exists if and only if $f$ is a bijection. Otherwise $f^{-1}A$ is only a notation for the preimage of a set $A$ with respect to $f$. You can't do the composition of two functions, $f^{-1}\circ f$, unless both of the functions exist.

Comment: @ThomasE. Thanks! I will look this up further to try and understand it better.

Comment: Sorry, Q, the new wording is no better --- it still suggests that you don't know what "one-one" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ (X,Y,f) $ be a function (defined as an ordered triple). Define $ f^{-1} \subseteq Y \times X $ by
$$
f^{-1} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{ (y,x) \in Y \times X ~|~ (x,y) \in f \}.
$$
Suppose that $ (X,Y,f) $ is one-to-one, i.e.,
$$
\forall x_{1},x_{2} \in X, ~ \forall y \in Y: \quad (x_{1},y),(x_{2},y) \in f ~ \Longrightarrow ~ x_{1} = x_{2}.
$$
Then $ (\text{Range}(f),X,f^{-1}) $ is a function, which allows us to solve the problem as follows.

> Let $ x \in \text{Dom}(f) $. Then there exists a $ y \in Y $ such that
>
> - $ (x,y) \in f $, equivalently, $ (y,x) \in f^{-1} $; hence,
> - $ y = f(x) $ and $ x = {f^{-1}}(y) $, as both $ f $ and $ f^{-1} $ are functions.
>
> Therefore, $ x = {f^{-1}}(y) = {f^{-1}}(f(x)) $.

> Let $ y \in \text{Range}(f) $. Then there exists an $ x \in X $ such that
>
> - $ (x,y) \in f $, equivalently, $ (y,x) \in f^{-1} $; hence,
> - $ y = f(x) $ and $ x = {f^{-1}}(y) $, as both $ f $ and $ f^{-1} $ are functions.
>
> Therefore, $ y = f(x) = f({f^{-1}}(y)) $.

Comment: Understand it now, thanks a lot! I like these types of proofs a lot more than differential equation and linear algebra proofs. It just seems a lot more logical to me.

Comment: @Q.matin: No problem! Let me mention that if $ (X,Y,f) $ is a one-to-one function, then we cannot immediately say that $ (Y,X,f^{-1}) $ is a function. This is because $ f $ may not be onto. However, we can definitely say that $ (\text{Range}(f),X,f^{-1}) $ is a function, and this is precisely what I have shown in my solution.

Comment: Thanks! And what is X,Y in this case? Are they sets?

Comment: Think of $ X $ as the domain of $ f $ and $ Y $ as the codomain of $ f $. These are definitely sets. :)

Comment: Ah, understand. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually sorry, I do not get it. If Y is the codomain then wouldn't $(Y,X,f^{-1})$ and $(Range(f),X,f^{-1})$ be the same thing?

Comment: No. If $ (Y,X,f^{-1}) $ is to be a function, then I require that for every $ y \in Y $, there exists an $ x \in X $ such that $ (y,x) \in f^{-1} $. This is the same as saying that for every $ y \in Y $, there exists an $ x \in X $ such that $ (x,y) \in f $. However, this is not true if $ (X,Y,f) $ is not onto. For example, $ (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R},\{ (x,e^{x}) ~|~ x \in \mathbb{R} \}) $ is a function, but $ (\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R},\{ (e^{x},x) ~|~ x \in \mathbb{R} \}) $ is not. This is because the mapping $ x \longmapsto e^{x} $ from $ \mathbb{R} $ to $ \mathbb{R} $ is not onto.

Comment: Let $ f = \{ (x,e^{x}) ~|~ x \in \mathbb{R} \} $. Then $ \text{Range}(f) = (0,\infty) $ and $ ((0,\infty),\mathbb{R},\{ (e^{x},x) ~|~ x \in \mathbb{R} \}) $ is now a function.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the target to the range of $f$. Then $f$ is a bijection and the result follows.

P.S. I agree with Gerry Myerson's comment above.

---

Chapter 1. of *Algebra* of Marty Isaacs has more detailed explanation for this stuff.